# How to register Yahoo Mail `mailto` protocol handler in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, yahoo, yahoo-mail

how can i register the `mailto:` protocol handler for the [Yahoo Mail web client](https://mail.yahoo.com)?

I know the javascript to run should be smt like this:

```js
navigator.registerProtocolHandler('mailto', 'https://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?%s', 'Yahoo Mail');
```

The problem is, their email composition URL domain **compose.mail.yahoo.com** is not the same as their main one **mail.yahoo.com**, so running [`registerProtocolHandler`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler) in the **mail.yahoo.com** inspector console gives the error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'registerProtocolHandler' on 'Navigator': Can only register custom handler in the document's origin.
> at :1:11

... and you can't run it in a **compose.mail.yahoo.com** window because it immediately redirects away with an HTTP 302 to **login.yahoo.com** with an additional redirect (if you're logged in) to **mail.yahoo.com/d/compose**.

---

So i can register such an handler? I just need to find a way to execute that javascript in the context of **compose.mail.yahoo.com**, i think..

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer by myself, even though it's kind of an hack.

1. log out of Yahoo! Mail
2. go to the login page https://login.yahoo.com
3. set the handler like this:

```js
navigator.registerProtocolHandler('mailto', 'https://login.yahoo.com?.src=ym&pspid=159600001&activity=mail-direct&.lang=en-US&.intl=us&.done=https%3A%2F%2Fcompose.mail.yahoo.com%2F%3Fto%3d%s', 'Yahoo Mail');
```

That is a generic login link with a post-login redirect to the double-urlencoded URL present in the `.done` parameter, which translates to the **compose.mail.yahoo.com** link needed for yahoo mail.

Adjust the `&.lang=en-US&.intl=us` as needed to set your preferred language.

I don't know what the other parameters are for, exactly.

I got this URL by checking what/how **compose.mail.yahoo.com** redirects to via `curl`:

```bash
curl -L -i compose.mail.yahoo.com/?to=xxx@xxx.com


HTTP/1.1 301 Redirect
Date: Fri, 17 Nov 2023 16:43:31 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Server: ATS
Cache-Control: no-store
Location: https://compose.mail.yahoo.com/mrd/?to=xxx@xxx.com
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 332

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
referrer-policy: origin-when-cross-origin
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
x-frame-options: DENY
x-omg-env: norrin-green--istio-production-ir2-6cb7454cc6-qwvld
location: https://login.yahoo.com?.src=ym&pspid=159600001&activity=mail-direct&.lang=en-US&.intl=us&.done=https%3A%2F%2Fcompose.mail.yahoo.com%2Fmrd%2Fmrd%2F%3Fto%3Dxxx%40xxx.com
vary: Accept
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
content-length: 190
content-security-policy: script-src 'nonce-2dnbUx4mJ1RLHE1i43f1n+ZxjDBRnYSyNMmne9TtZ3DoZu/S'
date: Fri, 17 Nov 2023 16:43:32 GMT
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 13
server: ATS
Age: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Expect-CT: max-age=31536000, report-uri="http://csp.yahoo.com/beacon/csp?src=yahoocom-expect-ct-report-only"
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to setup a little redirect page on a website you possess, with a simple script like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
        if (urlParams.has('s')) {
            // if parameter "s" present, create URL and navigate
            const s = urlParams.get('s')
            document.location.href = `https://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?to=${encodeURIComponent(s)}`
        } else {
            // else, allow the user to register the handler
            function register() {
                const newHandler = `https://${document.location.host + document.location.pathname}?s=%s`
                navigator.registerProtocolHandler('mailto', newHandler)
            }
        }
    </script>

    <button onclick="register()">register protocol handler for mailto: links</button>
    <a target="_blank"
        href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com?cc=someoneelse@theirsite.com, another@thatsite.com, me@mysite.com&bcc=lastperson@theirsite.com&subject=Big%20News&body=Body+goes+here">Email
        test link</a>
</body>

</html>
```